# Liquibase contexts exclamation operator

Tags: liquibase

I am using liquibase 3.6 and I would like to achieve the following:

I have two changesets (enable-test.xml and disable-test.xml), the first one I want it to be executed when context == 'test' and the second one when the context != 'test'.

This is my changelog file:

```
databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

    <include file="init.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" context="main"/>
    <include file="enable-test.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" context="test"/>
    <include file="disable-test.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" context="!test"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

The second changeset is being executed even when the context == 'test'. Am I missing something?

Edit:

I set up the contexts in gradle:

```
liquibase {
   activities {
   main {      
      changeLogFile "liquibase-changelog.xml"
      url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world'
      contexts liquibaseContexts
      username 'XXX'
      password 'XXX'
     } 
  }
 runList = 'main'
}
```

Comment: How do you set up liquibase context?  Do you use spring-boot? If yes, then what version?

Comment: I set it in gradle, using liquibase gradle plugin.

Comment: Could you add some code from your `build.gradle` where you set the context?

Comment: @htshame I edited the question to include the gradle code

Comment: I assume `liquibaseContexts` = main,test ?

Comment: Yes, if it's just main the enable-test.xml changeset is not executed.

Comment: And just to be completely fool-proof: are you sure, that the changeSets in `disable-test.xml` weren't previously executed and there's no record in `databasechangelog` table about them?

Comment: If the context is 'main, test' both enable-test.xml and disable-test.xml changesets are executed.

Comment: @htshame yes I delete the database each time before running the gradle task

Comment: By the way, how do you trigger plugin execution?